# Different behaviour between scalar and parallel code

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp, schedule

I'm wondering why the following code produces different results in its scalar and parallel variants:

```
#define N 10
double P[N][N];
// zero the matrix just to be sure...
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        P[i][j]=0.0;


double xmin=-5.0,ymin=-5.0,xmax=5.0,ymax=5.0;
double x=xmin,y=ymin;
double step= abs(xmax-xmin)/(double)(N - 1 );
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic)
    for ( int j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        x = i*step+xmin;
        y = j*step+ymin;
        P[i][j]=x+y;
    }
}
```

This code produces not completely equal results in its two version (the scalar version has just the `#pragma ...` part commented out).
What I've noticed is that a very small percentual of the elements of `P[i][j]` in the parallel version are different from those of the scalar version, but I'm wondering why...

Putting the `#pragma` on the outer loop as suggested is mess...completely wrong results.

P.S.
g++-4.4, intel i7, linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, now I can see the problem. Your comment [on the last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338218/how-to-parallelize-correctly-a-nested-for-loops) didn't have enough context for me to see it. But now it's clear.

The problem is here:

```
    x = i*step+xmin;
    y = j*step+ymin;
```

`x` and `y` are declared outside the parallel region, so they are being shared among all the threads. (and thus a nasty race condition among all the threads...)

To fix it, make them local:

```
for ( int j=0; j<N; j++)
{
    double x = i*step+xmin;
    double y = j*step+ymin;
    P[i][j]=x+y;
}
```

With this fix, you should be able to put the `#pragma` on the outer loop instead of the inner loop.

Comment: yeah, fixed!
Now it works with the `#pragma ` in the outer loop!

Thank you!

Comment: There is also a second possibility to reassure that x,y is thread local. You can use the [`private`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#PRIVATE) or [`firstprivate`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#FIRSTPRIVATE) keyword in the pragma: `#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic) private(x,y)`

Comment: @linello,  think this answer deserves the green tick!